# "Access violation writing location" using Visual Studio to debug cmake project for Windows ARM64

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, arm

I'm trying to remotely debug a very simple CMake program on an Windows ARM64 machine from an X64 machine. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-remote-debugging?view=msvc-170).

The program has the following structure:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project ("CMakeARM64")
add_executable (CMakeARM64 "main.cpp")
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   // exception thrown on this line
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```json
// CMakeSettings.json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "arm64-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_arm64_x64" ],
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

After setting up the remote debugger, when I run the program in Visual Studio an exception is thrown:

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF72B5730E8 in CMakeARM64.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00007FF72B574C38.

The debugger indicates that this happens on line 4 of the main.cpp file (hence at the beginning of main). I don't know how to investigate the reason of the crash further.

What I've noticed is that Visual Studio deploys the executable of the target to

> C:\Windows Default Deploy Directory\ARM64\CMakeARM64.exe

on the target machine.
When I try to run ./CMakeArm64.exe from within that directory, the program executes correctly and "Hello World!" is printed on the terminal.

Any clue on what might be going on here?

When I click on "Go to Disassembly" (the output below refers to when the writing location was 0x00007FF770794C38), Visual Studio shows this:

```
// ...other instructions
00007FF7707930CE  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930D0  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930D2  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930D4  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930D6  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930D8  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930DA  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930DC  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930DE  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930E0  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930E2  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930E4  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930E6  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
--- C:\Users\user\source\repos\CMakeARM64\main.cpp ----------------------------
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
00007FF7707930E8  std  // exceptions seems be triggered here
00007FF7707930E9  jnp         __gsfailure+1340h (07FF7707930A8h)  
00007FF7707930EB  test        eax,0A90157F4h  
00007FF7707930F0  not         byte ptr [rbx]  
00007FF7707930F2  add         cl,bh  
00007FF7707930F4  std  
00007FF7707930F5  add         eax,dword ptr [rax]  
00007FF7707930F7  xchg        eax,ecx  
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
00007FF7707930F8  add         byte ptr [rax],al  
00007FF7707930FB  mov         al,1  
00007FF7707930FD  ?? ?????? 
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
00007FF7707930FE  xor         byte ptr [rcx-2FFFFF98h],dl  
00007FF770793104  add         cl,al  
00007FF770793106  stc  
00007FF770793108  jmp         main+19h (07FF770793101h)  
00007FF77079310A  call        qword ptr [rdi-2F000018h]  
00007FF770793110  add         ecx,esi  
00007FF770793112  add         byte ptr [rcx-2FFFFF98h],dl  
00007FF770793118  or          byte ptr [rbp+100F940h],cl  
00007FF77079311E  ?? ?????? 
00007FF77079311F  ?? ?????? 
    return 0;

//...other instructions
```

Comment: Interesting.  Did you try 'View Disassembly'?  Even if you don't fully understand it, it might make interesting reading (and you could post it here - but not as an image please).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't know how to read assembly code but I pasted parts of the assembly output in my post. The full output is here https://pastebin.com/uzRbTq5m

Comment: That's OK, I've seen enough.  That's Intel 32 bit (x86) assembly, so you're not going to get very far trying to run that on ARM.  So you need to figure out a way to persuade the remote debugger to launch the right binary, something which I don't know how to do I'm afraid, but hopefully that will  put you on the right track.

Comment: Sorry, correction: it's x64 assembly.  But, that said, same difference, it obviously won't run on ARM.

Comment: Ok, I see that is very strange because when I run `dumpbin /headers ./CMakeARM64.exe`, the output shows: "FILE HEADER VALUES  AA64 machine (ARM64)"

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure _that_ file is OK because you can run it standalone, but are you also building an x64 variant?  I think you must be, because that seems to be the one that the remote debugger is launching.  I don't grok CMAKE, so I can't help with the details.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Windows on Arm supports X86 emulation on Windows 10 and additionally X64 emulation on Windows 11 versions. So its OK to run X64 and X86 assembly instructions, which is why the local exe runs.
However you will need the right remote debugger version to support the right instructions you are debugging. So if the app is X64 then install the Visual Studio 2019 X64 remote debugger client.